# Es6 way to create an Immutable map of records from an array

Tags: ecmascript-6, immutability

in this example ProjectCategory extends Immutable.Record

```
const ProjectCategoryRecord = Immutable.Record({
  id: 0,
  title: 'Default Title',
  description: 'Default Description',
  projects:  []
});

class ProjectCategory extends ProjectCategoryRecord{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}
```

i am currently creating these from an array of json objects:

```
let entityMap = OrderedMap();
entities.forEach((entity) => {
    entityMap = entityMap.set(entity.id, new ProjectCategory(entity))
});
```

i think there is a way to do it like:

```
let entityMap = OrderedMap((entities) =>{
    ...
})
```

but i cant make it work.... Is it not possible because OrderedMap is immutable???

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a good solution - but i am not sure

```
let entityMap = OrderedMap(entities.map(function (object) {
    return [object.id, new ProjectCategory(object)]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const map = OrderedMap(arr.reduce(
    (acc, obj) => ({
        ...acc,
        [obj.id]: new ProjectCategory(obj),
    }), {}));
```

If you still think it is not clean enough,
use [extendable immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extendable-immutable) and customize your constructor.